# Get Node js Server Url

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I am new to node.js. I just installed node.js on my production server it was installed correctly and node.js is running on my putty cli the problem is I cannot access it on my browser. I think  my problem is because I installed created my server on a subdirectory inside a subdomain  e.g. subdomain.example.com  here is my code

```
                var http = require('http');

                //create a server object:
                http.createServer(function (req, res) {
                  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
                  res.end(); //end the response
               }).listen(3000); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Now I am trying to access the node.js server by going to this address  subdomain.example.com:3000 but I am getting no results. Please help Thanks!

Comment: You are creating a local server ... try http://localhost:3000

Comment: Sir I am trying to access it on browser and I am currently on production

Comment: Try checking out nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback